# A Dilemma That I Stumbled Up On

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As those who read through a few of my previous questions would know, I am after Brown numbers, hunting for more of them.

It was during my hunt that I stumbled up on this particular thought : **"A pair of numbers whose product correspond to a factorial number has an arithmetic mean that is in a pair of Brown numbers whose other number is the inverse of the factorial obtained"**

A mathematical statement (I had to add an 'if' ; sorry for that) for this is as follows:

> If $\exists n : (m - 1)(m + 1) = n! \implies \exists m : \lbrace m,n \rbrace \in \mathbb{B}$ ($\mathbb{B}$ represents a set of Brown numbers in my way of writing)

Or say, if the predecessor and successor of $m$ gave a factorial as a product, then $(m,n)$ ($n$ = inverse of the factorial) is a valid pair of Brown numbers.

You all and I can understand that this is just a statement that arose from a trivial rewrite of Brocard's problem. But the problem is : why is it so difficult to find such pairs $\lbrace m,n \rbrace$ ? Why can't we find a square number that is one more than a factorial (other than the ones we've found till today as solutions for Brocard's problem)?

Comment: I don't understand your statement - you use $m$ and $n$ both as free and bound variables. Maybe write it in clear natural language as well?

Comment: @NoahSchweber , that's what I gave a "bold" formatting....

Comment: If that is still insufficient, well, I'll add it.

Comment: Indeed, this could be cleared up a bit. Even as someone that has this problem on his 'to look at' research list and have read papers on this problem, I had never heard of Brown Numbers - which feels like someone trying to get a name. Simply stated, the problem is just why is it 'difficult' to find $(m,n)$ such that $n!+1=m^2$; that's all that really need be said. My best answer is that depending on how you write it, either you're trying to relate multiplicative and additive structures or you're trying to find numbers who's factors are likely close but still large - and primes aren't

Comment: Or perhaps the best answer, is because there are likely not very many to be found....period.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life , I was pondering over  this one idea yesterday - a function to measure the density of primes in the composition of a composite number. Maybe that should help to solve the problem of finding pairs $(m,n)$, right ?

Comment: Maybe the composition of primes is what that is to be taken into consideration when trying to find $(m,n)$ such that the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: @Spectre I'm not so sure that would help. You can prove lots of things about density without actually finding anything. For instance, I can prove density $1/4$ of positive integers are a multiple of $4$, but that doesn't help me find the multiples of $4$ (luckily that is easy). Similarly, you can prove BSD for 100% of elliptic curves and still not have proven BSD.

Comment: I mean, you may try finding the density of primes in a composite number, right ?

Comment: @mathematics2x2life , you may try finding a 'prime density' function that measures the composition of primes in any number.

Comment: For $n\le 10^5$, $n!+1$ is perfect square only for $n=4,5,7$. I doubt that I would have found any even for $n>10^5$

Comment: I am after bigger values, @Oldboy .. but I think I have to let my computer go free to calculate such stuff.....

Comment: @Spectre And what have you found so far?

Comment: @Oldboy , nothing much but one sure thing (my belief) that there exists some factorial that can be represented as the product of the predecessor and successor of the next Brown number.

Comment: @Oldboy I run the tests using Python, so if it exceeds the limit, it gets stuck.. so I can't afford to let it run for large numbers.